# d3 scale with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I use [scale.scaleTime()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) with type Typescript and Angular 6.
The scale function:

```
import * as scale from 'd3-scale';
public xScale: ScaleTime<number, number>;

this.xScale = scale.scaleTime()
  .domain([
    new Date('2018-01-02'),
    new Date('2018-04-02')
  ])
  .range([
    0,
    100
  ])
  .clamp(true);
 this.xTicks = this.xScale.ticks(6);
```

But in template I see the error:
member xScale is not callable. I have already installed typings

```
npm install --save-dev @types/d3-scale
```

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP Storm notification, not an error of Typescript itself. It seems to be that I need to check typescript plugin